# Why is the calculation on `long` datatype giving a wrong answer?

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to perform a division on a `long` variable type. But whenever the platform tries the input of `1000000000000000` , my code breaks and gives a random output. What seems to be the problem here?

```
int main(){
    long var, ans;
    cin>>var;

    if (var %2 == 0)
    {
        ans= long(var/2);

        cout<<ans;
    }
    else{
        ans = -(long(var+1)/2);
        cout<<ans;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling it with `g++ codename.cpp`.

Comment: Most likely, you are building for a platform where `long` is 32 bits large (confirm by printing `sizeof(long)` ). But `1000000000000000` doesn't fit into a 32-bit integer. `cin>>var` then fails, but you don't check for failure and proceed to perform computations on an uninitialized variable holding random garbage.

Comment: try long long instead.

Comment: The first thing to do when you encounter a problem like this is to look at the value that `var` actually got. Either run the code in a debugger and inspect it or write the value to the console: `std::cout << var << '\n';`. The solution may well be to change to `long long`, as one of the comments suggests, but don't do that until you know what the problem is and why that would fix it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik is right! That helped. It was ```long long``` that i needed. Thanks.